# Get UserData and save it in text file

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am working on script where I have to save ec2 instance 'UserData'  and save it to text file.

Condition 1. I don't want to login to each instance and pull from there as instance may not in 'running' state. So i need to do it without login to the ec2 instance

Condition 2. I need to do in from powershell script.

I found the powershell cmdlets "(Get-EC2InstanceAttribute -InstanceId $tid -Attribute userData).UserData"  where $tid is instance id. but I don't know the format of output this commands give. AWS CLI also gives this kind of format.

Comment: " AWS CLI also gives this kind of format. " - what do you mean?

Comment: AWS CLI also gives same output as powershell cmdlets give.. I don't know how to save that in txt format. When I say text format, I mean human readable format so that I can understand the script which runs at the startup.

Thanks for looking into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird" format you are getting is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding of the user data.

Can't help with powershell, but if this is any help, in linux you could get the human readable user data as follows:

```
user_data=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute \
            --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
            --attribute userData \
            --query 'UserData' \
            --output text)

base64 -d <<< ${user_data}
```

Something similar should be doable in Windows.